# How to link report page to interactive grid form in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an application named demo_app. It contains 3 pages; these are respectively interactive report, form and interactive grid form:

- project_rpt
- project_form
- show_milestone_grid.

I want to link `project_rpt` with `show_milestone_grid`.

`project_rpt` has a column named "`milestone`". I want to link this column with `show_milestone_grid` that will show only those projects's milestone.

When I try to link this column, it is not showing any column for that page.

Example is as below.

```
page:project_rpt

project              description            milestones    
----------   
A                    test                   2      
B                    test2                  3
```

so when I click on milestones for project A, it should show below:

```
Page:show_milestone_grid

Project                  milestones    
----------    
 A                       my_mstone_1    
 A                       my_mstone_2
```

I am not able to link report page with interactive grid form. For normal form I can link, but I want to link grid form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how:

- as you've already created `project_rpt` and `show_milestone_grid` pages, I'll presume that everything's left as the Wizard did
- on `show_milestone_grid` page (interactive grid, right? Let's name it "Page 3"), create an item and name it `P3_MILESTONE`
- set `P3_MILESTONE`'s type to **hidden** (you aren't really interested in seeing it)
- modify its query and add a `WHERE` clause as `where milestone = :P3_MILESTONE`
- on `project_rpt` page (interactive report; that would be "Page 1"), navigate to report's **attributes** and

  - set link column to "Link to custom target"
  - target is Page 3 (`show_milestone_grid`)
  - in **set items**, set previously created `P3_MILESTONE` to accept value of the `#MILESTONE#` column from Page 1 (`project_rpt`)

That's all - save & run. When you click the link column in the interactive report (Page 1), you'll be redirected to interactive grid (Page 3) whose `P3_MILESTONE` item will accept value of the interactive report's `MILESTONE` column and filter result row set in the interactive grid.

Comment: Thanks for reply but Still it is not showing. I created hidden column in page 3  :P3_MILESTONE . I try to create link on page1 but it not showing any item- and value for set items in default select list for page 3. So i just write down as you suggested but it is giving run time error "ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "P3_MILESTONE" in application "49043".". let me know if you want screen shots.

Comment: Well, I was writing an answer by actually *programming* that, so - yes, it works if you do it correctly. Instead of screenshots, you'd better create a sample application on apex.oracle.com, provide credentials and someone will take a look.

Comment: Thanks. I created page item and now it is working fine.